# In dual boot Linux & Windows OS in a computer, the first browser's site gets logged off

Tags: security, login, browser

Why as we manage dual boot Linux & Windows OS in a computer, after browsing a site we restart into other OS and visiting, logging in on the site by using the same browser, next after exiting and we are back to the previous first OS and browser, in that site we automatically gets logged off (if stay still in the browser will always autologin)?
How to evade and keep from getting this poor behavior ?

Answer (score 3):

When you first login to the website with one OS, the site will store a cookie to the browser. This cookie is not shared between the operating systems, so when you switch to the other OS and visit the site, the site sees the browser has no cookie, presents a login prompt, and invalidates the old cookie associated with your account server-side.

When you switch back to the original OS, it presents the original cookie from the first login, which has been invalidated by the second login. So the site presents the login prompt again, and after a successful login, invalidates the second cookie and creates a third one.

To avoid this, you would have to find a way to make the two browsers in the different OSs synchronize their cookie stores with each other.